What can go wrong in synthesising MOFs that would lead to oxide formation and not a MOF?
I'm trying to synthesis a metal–organic framework (MOF) through a solvothermal method, using metal nitrates and 2-methylimidazolate (2-MeIM) as precursors, $\ce{MeOH}:\ce{H2O}~(35:5)$ as solvents, and cetyltrimethylammonium bromide (CTAB) as a modulator as well. However, the XRD analysis of the dried sample suggested the formed structure belong to metal oxides, not a MOF.
What went wrong here? Is it the CTAB or methanol? I'm trying to understand the reaction mechanism, but I can't find one in the literature.

Please always define your abbreviations, sources and reaction conditions (precursors, $p,$ $T$) as precisely as possible. I took a liberty to provide some meaningful ones for you to verify, but since you've accepted previous edit changing the letter in your term, it doesn't appear that you have a solid understanding in your own process. The 35:5 ratio is also weird: where does it come from if you claim that you don't follow literature? Are you sure you are interpreting powder XRD data (I assume it was PXRD) correctly? What do simulated and measured diffractograms look like?

I'm really sorry about the confusion, I wrote it in a hurry so I admit it didn't come out well structured. Actually what I meant by 35:5 is the volumes I used of both, because I've already asked someone else and they mentioned it may be the water content that caused the oxidation, so I wanted to highlight that I only used 5ml of the water and 35ml of the methanol. I use an autoclave for the synthesis, I put it in the oven for 24 hours at 140C. I'm supposed to be following a certain paper but they used different modulator and synthesis method, plus they depended mainly on water as a solvent

And yes, the XRD were interpreted correctly. Actually I prepared 3 samples, each with different ratio of metal precursors, and the 3 had very similar PXRD patterns, so if there was something wrong here, it happened to the three samples as a whole, not just one so I can say it's my fault, no there's something wrong with the procedure as a whole, that's why I'm asking
